# Writing a make file for GLFW3

Tags: c, macos, makefile

i'm writing an emulator program and I need a graphics library. I have 4 files, the graphics library GLWF3 is installed in my includes folder. Im using MacOs Yosemite. I can't figure out how to get the makefile working though to include the glfw3 library. Thanks in advance!
Also note the only file including GLWF3 is graphics.h
**Makefile**

```
OBJ = graphics.o chip8.o

emulator:   $(OBJ)
    gcc -o emulator $(OBJ)

graphics.o: graphics.c graphics.h 
    gcc -c graphics.c

chip8.o:  chip8.c chip8.h
    gcc -c chip8.c


clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) emulator
```

Comment: How would you do it if you were just using by gcc itself and not in a makefile? Do it the same way in the makefile, for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build with a given library, you have to:

- tell the compiler how to find library header file
- tell the linker which what library at must link.

**Compilation**

To tell where are the headers, you must pass a `-I/path/to/dir` option to `gcc`. Often, the make `CFLAGS` variable is used to do so:

```
CFLAGS= -I/path/to/glfw/include/dir

graphics.o: graphics.c graphics.h 
    gcc -c graphics.c $(CFLAGS)

chip8.o:  chip8.c chip8.h
    gcc -c chip8.c
```

**Link**

To tell linker what library to use, and where it is located, option `-L/path/to/sofile` and `-lthelib` are used. Usually in `LDFLAGS` variable:

**Warning:** The `-l` options must come *after* the files to link (*.o files)

```
LDFLAGS = -L/path/to/libglfw/lib/dir
# if the so file name is "libglfw3.so", the "-l" option must be "-lglfw3"
LDFLAGS += -lglfw3

emulator:   $(OBJ)
    gcc -o emulator $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)
```

**`pkg-config`**

To not to have to deal with paths, you can use `pkg-config` tool: This tool will help you to set `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables. See [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_pkgconfig) for installation instructions..

Hence, you makefile will looks like:

```
OBJ = graphics.o chip8.o
# calling program "pkg-config" and store result in CFLAGS variable
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glfw3)
# calling program "pkg-config" and store result in LDFLAGS variable
LDFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --ldflags glfw3)

emulator:   $(OBJ)
    gcc -o emulator $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

graphics.o: graphics.c graphics.h 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c graphics.c

chip8.o:  chip8.c chip8.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c chip8.c

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) emulator
```